# Windows Batch make multiple copies of a file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to make 726 copies of a single file with the file name incrementing, i.e. `00001_2.jpg`, `00002_2.jpg` etc.:

```
for /l %%A in (1,1,726) do (
    set /a i+=1

    rem Add leading zeroes:
    set FileName=00000!%%A!_2
    rem Trim to only four digits, from the end
    set FileName=!FileName:~-5!
    rem Add "output_" and extension again
    set FileName=!FileName!%%~xf
    rem Rename the file
    copy "2-original.jpg" "!FileName!"

)
```

This is just producing one file named `!FileName!` over and over again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You did not enable delayed expansion.

Comment: You may try this: `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` & `set "i=100000"` & `for /l %%A in (1,1,726) do (` & `set /a i+=1` & `copy "2-original.jpg" "!i:~1!_2%%~xA"` & `)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Squashman, this worked

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /l %%A in (1,1,726) do (
set /a i+=1

rem Add leading zeroes:
set FileName=000000%%A_2
rem Trim to only four digits, from the end
set FileName=!FileName:~-7!
rem Add "output_" and extension again
set FileName=!FileName!.jpg
rem Rename the file
copy "2-original.jpg" "!FileName!"

)
```